# Is there an equivalent for the ACCUM operator (',') from Oracle Text in postgres text search?

Tags: postgresql, oracle-text

Oracle Text search queries can contain a comma operator (a.k.a ACCUM), which basically gives a score depending of the number of tokens with a match.

Is there an equivalent in postgres text search?
From what I saw only AND,OR, and NOT operators are supported.

Comment: Did you read the manual about full text search within PostgreSQL? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch.html

Comment: Yes. I couldn't find something like this

Comment: What about ts_rank() ? PostgreSQL fulltext search works very different, but the end results could be the same. You have to test it and check your results with your content.

Comment: The score doesn't help - a query doesn't get a higher score if more then one term was matched

Comment: It does get a higher score, at least in my testcases. Could you show us your testcases to help you to fix your problems?